# CMakeLists.txt in project with multiple files

Tags: c, cmake

[linking errors.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mezRn.png)
Hellow. I have a project with eight .c and eight .h files. How should i write CMakeLists.txt to solve include dependences for all of them? Creating libraries isn't the way, because every file depends on some others.
Thank you!

My CMakeLists.txt was like

```
  cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
  project(calc-2.4.0)
  set(SOURCE_EXE main.c expmath.c interface.c container.c
  polnot.c error.c getelem.c dbg.c
  buildctrl.h expmath.h interface.h container.h
  polnot.h error.h getelem.h dbg.h)
  add_definitions(-Wall -O2)
  add_executable(calc ${SOURCE_EXE})
```

and

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(calc-2.4.0)
set(SOURCE_EXE main.c expmath.c interface.c container.c
polnot.c error.c getelem.c dbg.c)
add_definitions(-Wall -O2)
add_executable(calc ${SOURCE_EXE})
```

So linter can't see definitions anyway.

Comment: Are all source files supposed to generate a *single* or *multiple* executable programs? And what have you tried? How did your attempt work or not work? Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I used netbeans for long time and now I want to switch to atom. This project successfully compiled by netbeans. And now I try to generate compile_commands.json for atom linter.

Comment: Both those CMakeLists.txt files are fine, and should create a build-system that will build your `calc` program.

Comment: What error are you getting? That looks fine from what I can see.

Comment: I use only cmake -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=1 to create compile_commands.json file for gcc-linter in atom.

Comment: @Chrono Kitsune look at right bottom corner. There are logs of gcc-linter.

Comment: Is `.` in your include paths list in your configuration page (or in a `.gcc-flags.json` file—see the **File/Project-Specific Settings** section of the [linter-gcc docs](https://atom.io/packages/linter-gcc))?

Comment: Yes, I have all of it, but nothing helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to add all header files to your CMakeLists.txt. It should be sufficient to add the folders the header files are in. The required cmake command is [include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/command/include_directories.html).

My recommendation is the following:

- Add all *.cpp and header only files
- Add all required header files using `include_directory`

Example:

```
  cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
  project(calc-2.4.0)
  set(SOURCE_EXE main.c expmath.c interface.c container.c
  polnot.c error.c getelem.c dbg.c
  buildctrl.h
  )
  add_definitions(-Wall -O2)
  include_directory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
  add_executable(calc ${SOURCE_EXE})
```

- `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` points to the current source dir
- I recommend to move the sources into a subdirectory of the folder your top `CMakeLists.txt` file is in. See [Project Structure](http://www.th-thielemann.de/development/cmake/cmake_structure.html)